# TDWALLETERROR(543): Teradata Wallet error. The helper process is already being traced

Tags: teradata

When I start my jobs using fast export they sometimes end with an error:

```
TDWALLETERROR(543): Teradata Wallet error. The helper process is already being traced
```

When I restart them, they work. 
I'm using saved-key protection scheme.

Can someone explain to me why is that error occuring and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a trace activated in one of the scripts, run in the system.
Teradata has a shiffer code that attempts to validate if tracing is running during the wallet invocation - which triggers this error.